# Swift 3 cannot subscript a value of type 'String' with an index of type 'String' using SwiftyJSON and Alamofire

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, alamofire

This is the code, i was making a bitcoin price tracker app and im new to ios development so i am struggling with this error :( any help is appreciated. I am using Alamofire and SwiftyJSON to do the json work. They are imported using cocoapods. This is the json im using: https://apiv2.bitcoinaverage.com/indices/global/ticker/BTCUSD

```
// Connect the UI
@IBOutlet weak var PriceLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var PercentageLabel: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var CurrencyPicker: UIPickerView!

var url : String = "https://apiv2.bitcoinaverage.com/indices/global/ticker/BTCUSD"

var Price : String = ""

var jsondata = ""


// Called before app is shown to user
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Request the JSON Data
    requestJson()
}


func requestJson(){
    Alamofire.request(url).response { response in
        print("Request: \(response.request)")
        print("Response: \(response.response)")

        if let data = response.data, let utf8Text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
            print("Data: \(utf8Text)")
            self.parseJSON(json: utf8Text)
        }
    }
}

func parseJSON(json: String){
    Price = jsondata["ask"].stringvalue **This is where it kicks an error**
}
```

Comment: You've defined jsondata as a String but you're trying to use it as a Dictionary? Try: var jsondata: [AnyHashable: AnyHashable] = [:]

Comment: Just tried that and it is giving the error: value of type 'anyhashable' has no member 'stringvalue'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
func requestJson(){
    Alamofire.request(url).response { response in
        if let data = response.data {
            self.parseJSON(json: JSON(data: data))
        }
    }
}

func parseJSON(json: JSON){
    Price = json["ask"].stringValue 
}
```

for get json from URL you can also use [responseJSON](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/Alamofire/4.4.0/Classes/DataRequest.html#/s:FC9Alamofire11DataRequest12responseJSONFT5queueGSqCSo13DispatchQueue_7optionsVCSo17JSONSerialization14ReadingOptions17completionHandlerFGVS_12DataResponseP__T__DS0_)

Comment: "value of type 'anyhashable' has no member 'stringvalue'", thats also using ninjaproger's solution

Comment: @WilliamGregory sorry i copy your code :). Right! **JSON** has no member `stringvalue`, but `stringValue`

Comment: Weird, it says exactly the same thing just this time 'stringvalue' is 'stringValue'

Comment: Works Great, thanks a lot!, voted your answer as correct :)